# How do I convert this h:form into xhtml form

Tags: jsp, xhtml, jsf

```
<h:form id="login">
    Email: <h:inputText id="email" value="#{user.email}"/>
    <h:commandLink id="signupLink"  value="signup" action="#{userManager.validate}"/>
</h:form>
```

To something like this:

```
<form action="#{userManager.validate}">
    Email: <input type="text" id="email" value="#{user.email}"/>
    <button type="submit" value="signup"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the `action` point to the servlet URL. Then write code in servlet's `doGet()` or `doPost()` to collect the request parameters and store in model objects and execute the business code. In the view, you can redisplay the request parameters using `${param.name}` in EL. Basically the same what JSF does under the hoods thus. [This is a good tutorial to learn JSP/Servlet](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html).